# Where can I find dislocated worker program participation data by US county?

Tags: usa, government, education, labor, longitudinal

Where can I find U.S. displaced worker data, particularly during the Great Recession? I found sets from 1995 to 2008 and 2015 to recent. However, I'm having trouble finding data for 2008-2014, particularly data at the county level. I would really like to see participation in dislocated worker programs by county. Does it exist? Any suggestions?

Comment: CPS Displaced Worker Supplement?  I can see biennial data from 1984 to 2018 on [IPUMS CPS](https://cps.ipums.org/cps-action/samples)

Comment: @sboysel Thank you! Yes, that is exactly what I need. If you put your comment in the answers, I'll mark it as the right one.

Comment: Glad it helps. I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The U.S. Census Bureau's Current Population Survey Displaced Worker Supplement contains this data. There exists biennial data from 1984 to 2018 on [IPUMS CPS](https://cps.ipums.org/cps-action/samples).